# Confusion over a Func<> predicate expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I have read about `Func<>`, which says it iss a delegate and you can use it like for example:

```
Func<class,bool>
```

means you send a class or anything and get a bool result, this is what I got!
but what does the following mean?

```
Func<Class, bool> predicate
```

I have no idea, can you make it clear for me?

Comment: Weird, that nobody has mentioned `Predicate<T>` yet, which is basically the same as `Func<T, bool>`.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer - that is a tiny sprinkle of syntactic sugar, not terribly useful for someone who is learning the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Func<MyClass,bool>` is a delegate *type*

In `Func<MyClass, bool> predicate` , predicate is a delegate *variable*.

You would normally see something like

```
Func<MyClass, bool> predicate = c => c.IsValid;
...

if (predicate(myClass1))  DoSomething();
```

Comment: @it means I can send a lambda expression with MyClass,and get true or false?for example if there is field "Name" is my class,i can say,c=>c.Name=="Henk",if the name is there it gives me true,right?

Comment: Yes, you can use a delegate instance (in a variable, field or event) like a method. `if(predicate(a)) ...`

Answer (score 5):

The former will not compile since `class` is a registered keyword and can only be used [for class definitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes).

The latter is a [`Func<T, TResult>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2) which is a function that takes a parameter of type `T` and returns an object of type `TResult`. So in your case, the function takes an object of type `Class` and returns a `bool`.

The naming of `Class` is unfortunate but it’s actually allowed to use that identifier for a type. The following would be an example that takes such an object of type `Class` and then checks a property of it, returning `true` or `false` depending on the success of the comparison.

```
Func<Class,bool> predicate = obj => obj.Prop == "Foo";

var x = new Class();
x.Prop = "Foo";

Console.WriteLine(predicate(x)); // true
```

```
// with the following class definition
public class Class
{
    public string Prop { get; set; }
}
```

A `Func<>` object is *callable*, just like methods, so we can use parentheses to call it and pass the object here. This would be equivalent to a method like this:

```
public bool predicate(Class obj)
{
    return obj.Prop == "Foo";
}
```

But the usual way to use `Func<>` is using [lambda expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions) to be able to create functions quickly inline. This is very commonly used in [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) where you use lambda expressions, and as such `Func<>` objects, all the time:

```
var filtered = listOfOjects.Where(obj => obj.Prop == "Foo").ToList();
//                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                        this is the predicate function from above

// so you could also pass the predicate Func from above:
var filtered = listOfObjects.Where(predicate).ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

That's just how you instantiate the `Func`. Compare to a string:

```
string str;
```

If you want to instantiate and assign it at the same time, you do something like this:

```
Func<string, bool> isLongerThanThree = input => input.Length > 3;
isLongerThanThree("string"); // Returns "true"
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to the word `predicate`?

That's just the name of a parameter. Notice the similarity:

- `MyMethod(int myAge)`
- `MyMethod(List<bool> myBooleans)`
- `MyMethod(Func<Class,bool> myPredicate)`

---

Also notice the similarities between:

```
int myAge = 30;
```

`myAge` is a variable of type `int` who has been given the value of `30`.

```
Func<Class,bool> myPredicate = (x => x.IsAlive);
```

`myPredicate` is a variable of type `Func<Class,bool>` who has been given the value of `(x => x.IsAlive)`.

Answer (score 1):

`Func<>` is a delegate which represents a method which return a result. C# provides signatures for up to 15 input arguments, which should be enough to represent all possible methods you will ever need :) 
it is hardly event to imagine method which has 15 input arguments. Beside `Func<>` there are also some special version of the delegate like `Predicate<T>` which is nothing else that `Func<in T, bool TResult>` or `Action<>` which represent a function without return value, return value is `void`.

[Delegates(C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/)

You can assign any method, static or instance or even anonymous with the matching signature to the `Func<>`. For example:

`Func<MyClass, bool> predicate = (myClass) => {return true;} //anonymoys method`

```
public class MyClass
{
    public bool MyPredicate(MyClass myClass)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public static bool MyStaticPredicate(MyClass myClass)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

Func<MyClass, bool> predicate = new MyClass().MyPredicate;
Func<MyClass, bool> staticPredicate = MyClass.MyStaticPredicate;
```